# Solving $(x^2-1)\ddot y-2x\dot y +2y=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Solving 
$$(x^2-1)\ddot y-2x\dot y +2y=1$$

I've solved the homogenous equation:

$$y=A(x^2+1)+Bx$$

Where A and B are constants of integration, but I can't for the life of me seem to remember how to find the private solution when coefficients aren't constants. I'd appreciate any hints.

Ron

Comment: @KennyLau maybe I'm overthinking. How exactly did you get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean $(x^2- 1)y''- 2xy'- y= 1$.  An obvious thing to try, since the right hand side is a constant, is y= constant.  With y= C, y'= y''= 0 so the equation becomes -C= 1 or C= -1.  y(x)= -1 satisfies this equation.

Comment: Oh I see what's needed.. But the solution is $ \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

By setting $y=u+\frac{1}{2}$ we have
$$(x^2-1)u''-2xu' +1(1+1)u=0$$
which is a [Legendre](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html) ODE.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2-1)\ddot y-2x\dot y +2y=1$$
An obvious particular solution is $y=\frac{1}{2}$

Add it to the solution of the homogeneous ODE :
$$y=A(x^2+1)+Bx+\frac{1}{2}$$